# Webpage moves when scroll up and down activates

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a webpage with a menu at the top. One option displays information that is not enough for the screen, so **the scroll up and down activates,** which is okay. But i noticed that when i clicked another option from the menu that has information that fits the screen, **the scroll does not activate**, which is okay but **the webpage appears to move** to the right because there is no scroll that  occupies space in the window. Is this normal? It looks weird because the webpage slightly moves.

I centered my page with:

```
margin-left:auto
margin-right:auto
```

Thanks!

**Problem**
The problem is that a webpage looks centered when the scroll is visible, when i click another link that DOES NOT need the scroll, the webpage shifts to the right because there is MORE SPACE on the screen because no scroll needs to be activated.

Comment: That is normal. Are you looking for something to get rid of the behavior...?

Comment: I have a hard time in understanding your problem. Don't you mean that the right vertical scrollbar disappears and reappears in your (non-MSIE) browser which caused that the website seems to move to right/left? If so, you could fix the vertical scrollbar by CSS.

Comment: Yes i wanted to get rid of that behavior, but if its normal....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

In your CSS if you want the vertical scroll bars to always be present.

Comment: No i don't want it to be always present i just don't want my webpage to move to the right when the scroll is not present

Comment: @bb2, then I fear you are stuck.  Is it that big a problem, do you have roughly 50% of your pages without a scroll bar?  Aren't you making assumptions about the user's viewport anyway?  If the movement is that bad, then this answer is the best compromise, the scrollbar will be visible but inactive.  The user wouldn't know any difference.

Comment: Yes, I tried your solution and it's good! After I read this I also found this recommendation in a blog. Thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

Well, Im not 100% sure what you mean but, you can always try

"margin: auto;"

And also you could try and add a class/id to your content called "scrollable" which you could then use jQuery or raw javascript to prevent/ensure that it does scroll

Comment: scrolling does work, but his website is moving to the left when no scrollbar is needed

Comment: Oh I see, then probably is an overflow issue